# Python string to float conversion

Tags: python, function, object, types, casting

Can someone explain why the x below can act as a function float()? Basically I dont understand what  means? is this a internal function or implicit object ?

```
>>> x=type(0.0)
>>> x
<type 'float'>
>>> x('9.823')
9.823
```

Comment: Because this is same as doing `x = float`.

Comment: Guessing it's the same as doing `x = float` and then calling `x('0.823')`. But never the less interesting, never thought of using the type object in junction with a function call : )

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly the same as writing `float('9.823')`.  In fact, you can easily see that as follows:

```
>>> type(0.0) is float
True
>>>
```

And you can use them in exactly the same way:

```
>>> float('9.823')
9.823
>>> type(0.0)('9.823')
9.823
>>>
```

It's just invokes the constructor for the `float` type.

Comment: so <type 'float'> is a constructor?

Comment: Well, it's a type that has a constructor, just as a class is a type that has a constructor (with the same syntax).

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the variable `x` to the type `float`. The command `type()` returns the type of whatever is inside the brackets. In your case, you provided the type command with a float and setting that return of float to your variable `x`.

Comment: I guess my question was what the operator <> means?

Comment: That is just how a type displays when you print it. Generally you don't use <> brackets in Python.

Answer (score 0):

It can act as the function float because you are effectively making `x = float`.

As an example, you could also, for instance do this:

```
x = type(1) #int
print x(1.1111) # will print 1
```